# HTML Layout - 1 on Left, Two Stacked on Right

Tags: html, css

**So I'm trying to create the following illustrated layout with images.. I need:**
 - Two stacked images on the right to be the same height as the left 
 - Width to not go off the page
 - Entire container to be centered 
 
 - Divs to be dynamic 
[image: Image Layout]

At the moment I have not been successful..

**Code so far:**

Style:

```
 #menucontainer{position:absolute; display:block; width:100%; margin-top:5%;  margin-left:0 auto; text-align:center }
    #menucontainer div{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; padding:0 !important}
    #highscore, #howto{display:inline-block; ;}
    #highscore img, #howto img{width:100%; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888}
    #play{width:100%;  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888}
    #left{width:50%; }
    #right{margin-left:1%; width:40%;}
    #highscore{margin-top:3.5%}
    #centerit{margin:0 auto;}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="menucontainer">
  <div id="centerit">
    <div id="left">
        <img src="pics/play.png" id="play"/>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
       <div id="howto"><img src="pics/howto.png" /></div>
       <div id="highscore"><img src="pics/scores.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the sizes of the images? how is it possible to maintain their aspect ratios and fill the space at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to accomplish this. I used `div` with `display: table` It may be a little tricky getting the image heights to match up you should be able to play around with it and get it to work. Heres what I used

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="left">
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x216" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="nest">
          <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200x103" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200x103" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

.box {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  background: lightblue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.left, .right {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;
}
.nest {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I made a [Fiddle if you want to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/fx4j0db6/2/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example using `table` element

**Note adjust border-spacing for space between cells**

style `#main_container` with text-align:center and vertical-align:middle

```css
#main_container{
  display:table-cell;
  width:700px;
  height:700px;
  border:solid;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
td{
  border:solid;
 
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
table{
   border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_container'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>
      LEFT
    </td>
    <td class='right'>
        IMAGE1
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    Image2  
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>
      <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSie95sTN5Pbo6and9-fWIXSSjXhDTOy87TFsxfw3ddF6JnNS6'>
    </td>
    <td class='right'>
         <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSie95sTN5Pbo6and9-fWIXSSjXhDTOy87TFsxfw3ddF6JnNS6'>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <img src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLCSh6c5nj_PGN1TjWJ7LrL4-MxaxNaZ51uL5BV7vlAgJQoVDJjQ'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```