# How to arrange some elements vertically within a line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want my images arranged like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dijuv.png) pic.
Where some of the images are displayed on top of eachother while being in line with the other images

I tried using divs but this put each image onto its own line

Comment: Learn grid layout : )

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645242/html-layout-1-on-left-two-stacked-on-right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

you can use divs and position them with css or using a table in html is a great solution as well(you can even control the column and rows width in html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).